# Inheritance, retrieves value from private properties of base class instead of the derived one

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface, derived-class, base-class

I am trying to retrieve a value from a overrides public variable, but surprisingly am getting the value from private property ?

Find below the code,

Project - Interfaces - Contains - IAnimal, IPoo

Project - ML - Contains - AnimalBase, Cat, Dog, Poo, RadioactivePoo

Project - ConsoleApplication - Contains - Modules

```
Public Interface IAnimal

    ReadOnly Property Excrement() As List(Of Poo)

    Sub Eat()

End Interface


Public Class Poo

End Class

Public Class RadioactivePoo

End Class

Public Class AnimalBase(Of T)
    Implements IAnimal

    Private _Excrement As List(Of Poo)

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Excrement() As List(Of T)
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable Sub Eat() Implements IAnimal.Eat
        If _Excrement Is Nothing Then
            _Excrement = New List(Of Poo)
        End If
        _Excrement.Add(New Poo)
    End Sub

    Private ReadOnly Property Excrement1 As List(Of Poo) Implements IAnimal.Excrement
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Public Class Dog
    Inherits AnimalBase(Of Poo)

    Private _Excrement As List(Of Poo)

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Excrement() As List(Of Poo)
        Get
            Return _Excrement
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub Eat()
        If _Excrement Is Nothing Then
            _Excrement = New List(Of Poo)
        End If
        _Excrement.Add(New Poo)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Cat
    Inherits AnimalBase(Of RadioactivePoo)

    Private _Excrement As List(Of RadioactivePoo)

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Excrement() As List(Of RadioactivePoo)
        Get
            Return _Excrement
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub Eat()
        If _Excrement Is Nothing Then
            _Excrement = New List(Of RadioactivePoo)
        End If
        _Excrement.Add(New RadioactivePoo)
    End Sub
End Class


Module Module1

    Sub Main()


        Dim dog As IAnimal = New Dog
        dog.Eat()
        'Dim dogPoo As Poo = dog.Excrement

        Dim cat As IAnimal = New Cat()
        cat.Eat()
        'Dim catPoo As RadioactivePoo = cat.StronglyTypedExcrement()

        Console.WriteLine(dog.Excrement.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(cat.Excrement.ToString)

        Console.Read()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I am trying to retrieve value from dog.Excrement / cat.Excrement, but surprisingly am getting it from dog.Excrement1 (which is private, but implemented by IAnimal Class).

How to get the value from Excrement ? , but when i tried to access, it returns nothing. [see the pic, which lists the values, where you can see the public Excrement function has value, and private has nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMUvD.png)

Comment: **[Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels)**  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You've declared the variables `dog` and `cat` to be of type `IAnimal`.  Thus, calls through those variables go the things that are declared to implement the interface.  If, instead, `dog` were declared to be of type `Dog`, you would access its own public property (and be unable to call to the member that implements the interface).

Comment: But have read in an article, to decouple the BL from the Main project. thus Main project has been referred to Interfaces only.